# pyspark createDataFrame does not have consistent output, forcing value of invalid type to become None

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We have two systems both using spark 1.6.1, but both systems have different output for the following code:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('abcd',123)], ['col_A', 'col_B'])
rdd = sc.parallelize([('abcd','123')])
a=sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, df.schema)
a.collect()
```

The first system will change the invalid string '123' to become None, as col_B is of type int

```
[Row(col_A=u'abcd', col_B=None)]
```

But the second system will raise an exception.

```
TypeError: LongType can not accept object in type <type 'str'>
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: Without knowing more, the obvious differences could be between python 2.x and python 3.x, or a configuration one, you could start by checking df.printSchema()

Comment: @EwanLeith Both df.schema are the same and we are using python 2.7

Comment: This behavior changes somewhere between 1.4 and 1.5 or 1.5 and 1.6 so if you see inconsistent results it is most likely due to some configuration issues. Nevertheless you should always type check before pushing data to JVM.

Comment: We found the problem. One system is using standard python 2.7 while the other is using anaconda python 2.7. Is there any way to standardize their behaviour?